# Find original item id with multiple links

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with a large amount of item ID's in column A and in column B I have a new replacement item ID. The replacement ID can also have a replacement ID, this could be repeated up to ~20 times.

What I would like to do is in column C find the original item ID.

I have previously been able to solve it with multiple `vlookup` but as the file grows its getting messy and hard to manage.

[image: Example]

Comment: Does column A and column B (separately) have no duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one formula you can use:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,A2)=0,A2,INDEX($C$1:C1,MATCH(A2,$B$1:B1,0)))`

How it works:

- `=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,A2)=0,A2` - checks whether actual ID is a replacement (occurs in column B above current line), if not a replacement, than use ID as original ID
- `=,INDEX($C$1:C1,MATCH(A2,$B$1:B1,0)))` - for replacement it looks for the original ID of the original item

I used a few assumptions:

- each ID is replaced at most once (when you replace again, you replace the new ID)
- each replacement is listed below the row containing its original ID

[image]